# React not rendering data from useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying out React hooks, and I'm very confused about what I'm seeing. 
I'm getting a JS object as a payload from my endpoint, and this will display and render fine if I pass the raw result:

```
...
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const Status = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('fetching status')
    const start = new Date()
    getStatus()
    .then(result => {
      console.log(`status fetched in ${(new Date() - start)}`)
      for (const key of Object.keys(result)) {
        if (!data[key]) {
          data[key] = {}
        }
        data[key]['status'] = result[key]
      }
      console.log(data);
      setData(result)
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      { console.log('rendering')}
      <h1>Status</h1>
      <span>{JSON.stringify(data)}</span>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Status
```

... and I get two "rendering" logs as expected.

But when I change it to actually use the processed data instead:

```
...
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const Status = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('fetching status')
    const start = new Date()
    getStatus()
    .then(result => {
      console.log(`status fetched in ${(new Date() - start)}`)
      for (const key of Object.keys(result)) {
        if (!data[key]) {
          data[key] = {}
        }
        data[key]['status'] = result[key]
      }
      console.log(data);
      setData(data) // <--- here
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      { console.log('rendering')}
      <h1>Status</h1>
      <span>{JSON.stringify(data)}</span>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Status
```

I don't get that second render, and the information isn't rendered on the page. Data is there as I verified in the console.log statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you pass the same object to `setData` which will not cause a re-render because it's the same object.

`React` is basically doing this `currentState === newStateFromSetState` which will return true because it's the same `object` reference.

You need to pass a new object to `setData` like this

```
setData({ ...data });
```

This will make sure the `object` that is passed to `setData` is a not the same `object` but it's better to just construct a new `object` than mutating the current one.

```
const updatedData = { ...data }

for (const key of Object.keys(result)) {
  if (!updatedData[key]) {
    updatedData[key] = {}
  }
  updatedData[key]['status'] = result[key]
}

console.log(data)
setData(updatedData)
```

Comment: This must be different from the class version of state updating, because I've been able to call `this.setState(prev => { //modify prev and return it }` and it causes a render

Comment: I've never tried to mutate and return prev, I just tested it and it indeed works, I guess react is doing something internally when returning something from `this.setState` callback

Comment: regardless, this is probably the more correct way to do it