# React not rendering data from fetch inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api, use-effect

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56230189/react-not-rendering-data-from-useeffect): but the data originates from a fetch() and there is a nested .then to get to the data object data.list_helado which is a list of dictionaries.

Why won't the data render on the page?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {Helados} from "../components/Helados";

function BiteroInfoPage() {

  // Initate array of helados (a data object of type dict) and their states
  const [helados, setHelados] = useState([]);

  // Fetch the list of helados initialized from database
  useEffect(() => {
  fetch("/list_initialized")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      const updatedData = [...data.list_helado];
      setHelados(updatedData);
    });
}, []);

  return (
    <div className="biteroInfo">
      <h1>Bitero Segments</h1>
      <Helados prop={helados}/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BiteroInfoPage;
```

Where Helados.js is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { List, Header} from "semantic-ui-react"

export const Helados = ({prop}) => {
console.log(prop)
console.log("Above returns: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]")
    return (
        <List>
            {prop.map((helado, index) => {
                return (
                    <List.Item key={index}>
                        <Header>{helado.study_name}</Header>
                    </List.Item>
                );
            })}
        </List>
    );
};
```

Comment: Are you sure `updatedData` is filled?

Comment: I think so? When I put a console.log(updatedData) below const updatedData I get console output as: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `useEffect` to look like this. You weren't handling `response.json()` correctly. You shouldn't have any nested calls.

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch("/list_initialized")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      const updatedData = [...data.list_helado];
      setHelados(updatedData);
    });
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately this is still not rendering for me.

Comment: @thunt Try adding `helados` in the square brackets in the end of `useEffect`.

Comment: @k450 thanks for this. Unfortunately, this created an infinite loop of calls in the console showing the data: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}], but still nothing actually rendering on screen.

Comment: Yeah, you don't want `helados` in the useEffect dependency array.

Comment: Can you console.log `prop` inside of `Helados` component, and post in your question what it contains?

Comment: I feel so silly... at some point I changed study_name to studyName. I will accept this answer as the correct solution, because the incorrect response.json() handling also contributed. Thank you!

Comment: No prob. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: Also, you can always look at the DOM and you would have seen there is a list of Headers. Don't let your eyes fool you into thinking that something isn't there, just cause it's invisible.